# php.ini not reloaded on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, php

Im trying to change something in php.ini - but after editing, saving the file and restarting apache no changes is updated.

I'm on **Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS**

- I have used phpinfo.php to locate the file in use:    **/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini**
- Changing that file through terminal, updating `short_open_tag` from Off to On, and saving the file.
- Typing `service apache2 restart` to make the changes go live

But no changes is updated. From phpinfo I can still see that `short_open_tag`  is Off.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you mention fpm, you need to restart fpm not apache, on debian based should be close to :

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

or just

```
sudo service php-fpm restart
```

reload can also do it instead or restart.

Comment: Aaaaaaaah. Thank you!